# javascript input field to number

Tags: javascript, input, numbers

I need to convert an input field into a number. So if the input field is empty, or contains letters, the number would be 0.

This doesn't work:

```
var trade_gold = document.getElementById('trade_gold').value;
if (trade_gold < 1) {
```

I've tried parseInt on it too, can't seem to work it. Any advice?

Comment: Try doing alert(trade_gold) first to see if it is the value you were expecting. If it is a number, parseInt will work.

Comment: Be more specific about what problems you are having with parseInt.  That is the normal way to parse strings into numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var val = document.getElementById('trade_gold').value,
    trade_gold = parseFloat(val) || 0;
```

Comment: Beat me to it, so I'll put my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/yKK2K/   (I use parseFloat, but it depends on the number you are expecting.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = document.getElementById('trade_gold').value;

value = parseInt(value, 10);

// parseInt will return NaN if the conversion failed
if (isNaN(value)) {
    value = 0;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

```
var trade_gold = 0;
try{
    trade_gold = parseInt(document.getElementById('trade_gold').value, 10);
}catch(e){}
```

Comment: The `try/catch` won't help. `parseInt` doesn't throw, but rather returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

this will checks whether the it's a number or not, and change the value to 0 if it's not.

```
var trade_gold = document.getElementById('trade_gold').value;
if (trade_gold.search(/[^0-9]/)>=0)
{
       // not a number
       trade_gold = 0;
}
```

Comment: what does [...) do in a regex?

Comment: checks whether the string has character(s) specified on the brackets or not

Comment: did i mistype something? @@ i'm sure i wrote [...] >.>

Comment: oh, that's because i just noticed that my regex is not functioning :P maybe i did really mistype it, but i didn't notice :P